# Python IDE that doesn't require saving to file

Tags: python, ide

I'm looking for a Python IDE where I can write Python files and run them without having to save the files to the disk.
(Perhaps an IDE where I can have multiple tabs open, each with a different Python file.)

Most IDEs which I've tried do force the user to save the code to a file before running it, so if you know of an IDE that doesn't, I'd love to hear about it.
(Note that I am *not* looking for a Python interpreter.)

Thank you in advance.

Note 1: Technically, such an IDE will most likely save a temporary file to the disk. Obviously, this is acceptable.

Note 2: The motivation for my request is to be able to write short or disposable pieces of code without having to bother with coming up with a filename and location for each and every one of them.

Note 3: I do know that the PyScripter IDE does exactly what I described, but I'd like to try something new (as it is not a very active project).

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: Peronally, I use PyCharm (which can't be beat) and just call each new creation `temp.py`, each overwriting the last. That way, I enver have to  bother with coming up with a filename and location for each and every one of them.

Answer (score 1):

[Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) Notebooks, while not an IDE, can execute python 2 &/or 3 *plus several other kernels* in multiple browser tabs without you having to come up with filenames, etc. - You can execute each cell in your notebook as and when you decide to, you can save the code as a python file or a notebook, export code and results, etc.

- Many of the IDE features such as syntax highlighting, etc. are present.
- Gratis & Open Source
- Cross platform